# I am thinking of installing Mint 17 Mate on a new computer without a dualboot ie uninstall the original windows 8. Is this a good idea?

Tags: windows-8, linux-mint

With no tech experience,I have previously dual booted an old xp computer with Mint13. Worked great. I am now getting a new computer with win8 installed and would prefer to use Mint17 Mate on it. Does it make sense to erase the win 8 and install Mint 17 as the sole OS?  I plan on using the windows 8 for the first few days I have the computer, simply to make sure the computer works correctly before I change the OS. After that, I will have no interest in using the win 8. I am not a gamer. I use the computer for a small business and personal use.  Thanks.

Comment: If you want Mint, then install Mint. We can't make that decision for you, or say if it's a good idea for you. Voting to close as "opinion-based". PS: Windows works for more than just games. ;)

Comment: The only downside to dual boot is that you keeps some hard disk space occupied with the extra OS (plus it adds a few seconds to startup time).  There are benefits to having another OS on the machine if you run into problems or have software or hardware with compatibility issues.  Removing an OS is a lot easier than putting a pre-installed one back if you decide later that you could use it.  If you're sure you don't need Windows, buy a computer without it and save some money on the license fee built into the price.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdfY25gDjK8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after all its your decision but if I was you I would have at least two O.S, a Linux based O.S and a Windows, the main reason? Software... there's plenty software who just don't work in Linux like Photoshop or CAD etc...

P.D Upgrade to Windows 10 will be free for Windows 8 users, maybe you want to wait.

Comment: "Upgrade to Windows 10 will be free for Windows 8 users" Got a reputable source for this claim?

Comment: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2688652/microsoft-indonesia-president-windows-9-will-be-free-to-windows-8-owners.html

Happen the same with Vista to 7.

Comment: Thanks also to fixer1234 for similar answer. I will go ahead and just dual boot.

Comment: There was never a free upgrade from Vista to 7. And yeah I've seen those "news" stories that link to a link to a link that says  Andreas Diantoro from "Microsoft Indonesia" said it might be free.  To me that isn't reputable; I'll believe it when I see it on a Microsoft site, until then it's just rumor. ;)

Comment: Would have agreed 5 years ago about dual booting for software compatibility. Today,though, most of the windows software I download installs and runs without issue on LM. I occasionally need to set up a new prefix but that's a small price to pay compared to the cost of Windows+antivirus.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are your computer will come with the ability to create recovery media; do that right away, then test the media to see if it works fine, and then wipe the drive and install Mint. This way if you change you mind you can always go back.

I would advise holding of for 31 days, as 14-30 days is typically the return policy for stores, beyond that you'd be typically be dealing with the manufacterer. After all new computers can have problems that you don't notice on day 1.